# Use Geometry Nodes Raycast to detect closest surface and place Object there

Tags: geometry-nodes, shrinkwrap

I'm trying to get a dynamic contact point for a shrinkwrap modifier. The normal projection of the shrinkwrap is not enough in my case, as i need the closest point of another surface. However i'm not having any luck in getting the values from the raycast back that i need.

Here is my current setup:
[image]
I would want to get the shortest ray, and at its hit point i want to spawn a simple icosphere, or other mesh. In my mind its quite simple to achieve, but i cant get it to work.

[image]

Comment: Just a few thoughts: It doesn't work this way because you use the sphere's *Geometry* for the *Set Position* and since the *Ray Cast* node also is connected to it, the *Ray Cast* node uses the sphere to cast rays from it. The *Set Position* node will move the vertices of the sphere to the hit position (=shrinkwrap the sphere). You need to do something with the circle's geometry (*Group Input > Geometry*). Also, you need the closest hit position. Maybe *Attribute Statistics* helps but this can only get you one value. You need the distance & location... you probably also need a *Sample* node...

Comment: You need 2 *Attribute Statistic* nodes then it kinda works. I'm just curious what do you need this for? The shortest distance makes the sphere jump over pits and stick it to bumps. Here is a demo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3nVt.gif. It reveals that the sphere sticks half into the ground because the origin is in the center. So I guess you have to move it "back" along the normal of the floor plane to gently touch the floor.

Comment: Thank you booth for your Tipps! I'll try it asap :) i need to visualize a theoretical contact point of a tire to the ground. I'll Post my result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your source-object is circular, can you dispense with ray-casting altogether and just find the closest point on the target-plane, to source **(0,0,0)** ?

[image]

Which does this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: And for non-circular object you could go through the bottom curve, capture the attribute of the distance to the nearest point on the top object, then use a statistics node to find the minimum, then find the lowest index with such value as the distance and then sample the point with that index.